# Profile completion after e-mail verification

Tags: security, email-verification

I'm building a web application for two different types of users, with a different registration form for each of them. I could split up those forms and send a verification e-mail after the form is validated.

But I'd prefer to have one general small form where the user enters his/her e-mail address and user type. The server then sends a verification e-mail with a link to further complete the profile, depending on the chosen user type.

Now my question is: should I include a password field in the small registration form? I have seen it before on many websites, but I can't see why I would include it. My plan is to make the user choose his/her password on profile completion. Nothing about the user will be stored until he/she completes the profile (I would securely hash the e-mail address with a timestamp in a url).

Answer (score 1):

In general, the developers ask all the details including password at the time of registration and they allow to login using the same password. However, there is an open risk of unverified user can access all or some of the feature of the application. Sometimes the application also provides time frame of 24-72 hours to activate the user account, within this period user can access account with some restrictions.

For sensitive applications, **you can ask for the password once the user verify the email address.** So, that you are assured about the verified user.

If you are providing the feature to access the user accounts without being verified, make sure that the unverified account users can access the account with restrictions according to your application context.

Comment: Only verified users will be able to access the application or their account. As I said before, the email will be securely hashed, together with a timestamp (I'm allowing a time frame of 24 hours). This hash will be appended to a url, and sent to the provided email address. So is there a security risk if I do it this way?

Comment: That's better you will only allow verified users to access the application. As you mentioned you are securely creating hash with a time-stamp for the verification process. There is no security issue, if you are using the strong hashing algorithm such as SHA256 or higher. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm)

Comment: In addition as a security perspective following should be taken care,
- Password reset URL, Registration URL should have unique token
- Unique token should be invalidated once used
- Unique token should be invalidated within 24-72 hours, as per application context
- Token should not be guessable 
- Password reset page should not contain any third party libraries/css/javascript as Referrer headers may leak the password reset URL and internal malicious user from third party can use it